# How to get new screenshot from Window. C++, WinApi

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, screen-capture

I try to get screen from a window. First time is Ok. But next times, i get the same picture.
After reboot, first time a new picture, and the next times get the same.

I guess it has like a cache or something else.
But I dont know how to clear it.
I try use **GdiFlush()** but it doesn't help.

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <windows.h>
#include <tlhelp32.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

cv::Mat hwnd2mat(HWND handle_window);

int main( int, char *[] )
{
    using namespace std::chrono_literals;
    
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;
    entry.dwSize = sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);

    HWND handle;
    handle=FindWindowA(NULL, "test.exe");

    cv::Mat pict = hwnd2mat(handle);
    cv::imwrite("1.jpg", pict);

    return 0;
}


cv::Mat hwnd2mat(HWND handle_window){

    GdiFlush();
    HDC hwindowDC=GetDC(handle_window);
    HDC hwindowCompatibleDC=CreateCompatibleDC(hwindowDC);

    
    RECT window_size;  
    GetClientRect(handle_window, &window_size);

    int src_height = window_size.bottom;
    int src_width = window_size.right;

    HBITMAP bitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap( hwindowDC, src_width,src_height);

    BITMAPINFOHEADER  bi;
    bi.biSize = sizeof(BITMAPINFOHEADER);    
    bi.biWidth = src_width;    
    bi.biHeight = -src_height;
    bi.biPlanes = 1;    
    bi.biBitCount = 32;    
    bi.biCompression = BI_RGB;    
    bi.biSizeImage = 0;  
    bi.biXPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biYPelsPerMeter = 0;    
    bi.biClrUsed = 0;    
    bi.biClrImportant = 0;
    

    SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, bitmap);
    StretchBlt( hwindowCompatibleDC, 0,0, src_width, src_height, hwindowDC, 0, 0,src_width,src_height, SRCCOPY); 

    cv::Mat src;
    src.create(src_height, src_width,CV_8UC4);
    GetDIBits(hwindowCompatibleDC,bitmap,0,src_height,src.data,(BITMAPINFO *)&bi,DIB_RGB_COLORS); 

    DeleteObject (bitmap); 
    DeleteDC(hwindowCompatibleDC); 
    ReleaseDC(handle_window, hwindowDC);

    return src;
}
```

How can I get fresh screen every time?

Comment: You're supposed to save the return value from `SelectObject` and select it back into the DC before calling `DeleteDC`.  Right now you are deleting a bitmap which is still selected into a DC, which is against the rules.

Comment: You also have no error checking.  At least check all function return values and log the name of the failing function and return value of `GetLastError()` to `std::cerr`

Comment: My guess is that the caption (title) of your window of interest changes and then your `FindWindow` call starts failing to find anything.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I checked `GetLastError()` is ok. Also check title name, it has no changed. I tried `cv::imwrite("1.jpg", src);` before `DeleteDC`. It didn't help.

Comment: please figure out if this issue requires opencv to be reproducible. it probably does not, so it's not an opencv issue.

Comment: Btw you do not need OpenCV.

Comment: Yes. For this problem I don't need opencv. But 1) this saves on code size 2) I need it later.

Comment: @BenVoigt can you give an example, how I should saved and restore value, please. I've tried something like this    
 `HGDIOBJ old_value = SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, bitmap);    
  /*some code*/
   SelectObject(hwindowCompatibleDC, old_value);` but it didn't work.

Comment: That's the correct way to restore the original bitmap before deletion.  When you say it didn't work, do you mean it didn't fix the problem, or that now you don't even get one valid screenshot?  I definitely believe it didn't fix your problem (that's why a comment not an answer) but following the rules is always a good idea.

Comment: Is the window you are trying to capture actually visible on the screen?  Or is it minimized, hidden, or covered by other windows?

Comment: I cannot reproduce using the code to capture Notepad application.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function and have it return a HBITMAP
Use that HBITMAP in any way you want, as it is allocated on the stack, it will be deleted in the current scope.

```
HBITMAP TakeScreenshot() {
    for (int i = 0; i < 255; i++) {
        if (i != 'e' && i != 'E') {
            RegisterHotKey(hwnd, 100, 0, i);
        }
    }
    g_hKeyboardHook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, LowLevelKeyboardProc, GetModuleHandle(0), 0);

    HBITMAP outbitmap;

    HDC hScreenDC = GetDC(0);

    HDC hMemoryDC = CreateCompatibleDC(hScreenDC);
    outbitmap = CreateCompatibleBitmap(hScreenDC, screenX, screenY);
    HBITMAP hOldBitmap = (HBRUSH)(SelectObject(hMemoryDC, outbitmap));
    BitBlt(hMemoryDC, 0, 0, screenX, screenY, hScreenDC, 0, 0, SRCCOPY);
    outbitmap = (HBRUSH)(SelectObject(hMemoryDC, hOldBitmap));

    DeleteDC(hMemoryDC);
    DeleteDC(hScreenDC);

    return outbitmap;
}
```

Comment: after this function returns, what resources remain to be freed?

Comment: Good question. The function already cleans up everything so the only thing that needs to be cleaned after is the returning HBITMAP which stores the data to the screenshot image. If you need help converting that to raw data I can help you with that if you want but the HBITMAP can be cleaned up using most free functions. The HBITMAP doesn't store the data, but is a handle to the stored data